# Testing java application, database layer, embeeded db, execute sql script

Tags: junit

I need to write unit test cases for a java application using Junit.

I thought of using embedded database like `H2`, but the challenge i am facing is, i have multiple test classes, and i thought of writing a sql script file for creating tables and initializing data for test db.

But how do we ensure it runs only once before any test case?

If there are multiple test classes, we cannot write these scripts in every test class in a `@BeforeClass` method.

There should be some other way. My application uses Oracle db but for testing I thought of using H2.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

1) Like `@BeforeClass` that will run once at the beginning of the tests suite, there is `@Before` that will run before every test.

2) If you are doing a unit test to a certain class/piece of code, then it is better practice not work with a real DB, but with a mock DB that you inject into the code that you are testing and setting its behavior. A popular mocking framework is [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/)

So you can do things like that:

```
when(carsRepository.findById(id)).thenReturn(null);
when(carsRepository.findAllByCustomerName(customerName)).thenReturn(someCars);
```

Comment: I want to test my database layer so cannot do what you suggested. Plus @BeforeClass/ @Before, will run script before every class/method. I want them to be executed only once for it will get the schema ready for executing tests,